# conditional align for bootstrap text-center

Tags: css, media-queries

I use a div like this..

```
<div id="book" class="justify-content-center text-center">
```

This is fine for desktops,  but when on mobile device I need to align text to the left instead. What do I need to add in my media query so that text is left aligned instead when on mobile device?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
// What do I add here to "override" the text-center so that it align to left instead?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Do not overwrite the bootstrap classes `justify-content-center text-center`. Overwrite the unique ID book only.

```css
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      #book{
        float:left;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="book" class="justify-content-center text-center">
    Test Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>

    @media (max-width: 575.98px) {
        .text-center {
            text-align: left !important
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
        .text-center {
            text-align: left !important
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
        .text-center {
            text-align: left !important
        }
    }
</style>

<div id="book" class="justify-content-center text-center">test</div>
```

This code generates the output you expect.

You should note that these CSSs are placed after the bootstrap tag.

result for big screen :

[image]

result for small screen :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap SASS, combining 2 Bootstrap classes to make a new class that does your job might be a better option. Consider the following:

```
.text-sm-left-md-right { // Give whatever name you want
    @extend .text-start; // or text-left if B4
    @extend .text-md-end; // or text-right if B4.
}
```

The above will have a text aligned left in **small** screens and then right from **medium** and above. This way you don't have to put the ID of an element here, and can reuse the class however many times you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the css right away

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .text-center {
    text-align: left !important;
  }
}
```

But you must import the CSS AFTER the bootstrap, or the bootstrap will override your CSS, instead of you override it. But there are other solution
write
`class="text-left text-sm-center"`

this mean on `sm` screen width, center the CSS, and left below `sm`
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/